# C# Find unknown substring that exists in each string

Tags: c#, arrays, list, duplicates, substring

We have a `List<string>`. Is there a way to find (and remove in this case) **unknown** substrings that exists in each string? At least in case 1, optionally in other cases.

```
            // Case 1:
            var l1 = new List<string>() {"FooOne", "FooTwo", "FooThree" };
            // Result should be:
            var r1 = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };

            // Case 2:
            //var l2 = new List<string>() { "BarOneBar", "BarTwoBar", "BarThreeBar" };
            // Result should be:
            //var r2 = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };

            // Case 3:
            //var l3 = new List<string>() { "OneFooTwoBar", "TwoFooThreeBar", "ThreeFooFourBar" };
            // Result should be:
            //var r3 = new List<string>() { "OneTwo", "TwoThree", "ThreeFour" };
```

**UPDATE:**
OK, case 2 and 3 looks unsolvable. But anyway there is a way to solve case 1. In this case each string begins with unknown set of characters that should be removed.

**UPDATE 2:**
We should replace as much duplicated characters as possible. `Foo` in case 1, not `Fo`, not `F`.

Comment: how do you define UNKNOWN  substring in your case?

Comment: What result should be for "TwoBarOneFoo", "TwoThreeBarFoo", "ThreeFooFourBar" ???

Comment: Last result `"OneTwo", "TwoThree", "ThreeFour"` contains `e`, `o`, and `T` in eash string. It have to be removed: `"Onw", "wThre", "hreFur"` ?

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder, don't look at case 2 and 3. Take a look at the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cases one and two are fairly straightforward.

Basically. you just compare the first character of all strings, if it is the same, remove the first character from all strings, repeat this until they are not the same.

Then do exactly the same thing about the last character.

I sadly don't speak C#. Here's some Python. The algorithm is exactly the same in any language, anyway. I have deliberately avoided using "pythonisms" where possible; the only Python-specific things you need to know are that `string[-1]` is the last character (same as `string[len(string)-1]`) and also string [:-1] is the string without its last character.

```
def remove_common_at_start_and_end(strings_to_check):

    # handle substring at the start of the lines
    finished_start = False
    while True:
        # any empty strings in the list would cause an exception so finish now
        if "" in strings_to_check:
            return strings_to_check
        # check if any first character might not be the same as the next one
        for i in range(len(strings_to_check)-1):
            if strings_to_check[i][0] != strings_to_check[i+1][0]:
                finished_start = True
        if finished_start:
            break
        # remove first character
        for i in range(len(strings_to_check)):
            strings_to_check[i]=strings_to_check[i][1:]

    # handle substring at the end of the lines
    finished_end = False
    while True:
        # any empty strings in the list would cause an exception so finish now
        if "" in strings_to_check:
            return strings_to_check
        # check if any last character might not be the same as the next one
        for i in range(len(strings_to_check)-1):
            if strings_to_check[i][-1] != strings_to_check[i+1][-1]:
                finished_end = True
        if finished_end:
            break
        # remove last character
        for i in range(len(strings_to_check)):
            strings_to_check[i]=strings_to_check[i][:-1]

    return strings_to_check

lines_to_check1=["FooOne", "FooTwo", "FooThree"]
print remove_common_at_start_and_end(lines_to_check1)
lines_to_check2=["BarOneBar", "BarTwoBar", "BarThreeBar"]
print remove_common_at_start_and_end(lines_to_check2)
lines_to_check2_2=["FooOneBar", "FooTwoBar", "FooThreeBar"]
print remove_common_at_start_and_end(lines_to_check2_2)
```

Output:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Note: the function in this code does not preserve the array that is given to it as a parameter. One can add a copy at the start to avoid this.

The third case is solvable, but the only idea about it that I have is to loop through all possible substrings in the first string and check for them in the others. I don't have the time to code this right now. You loop through all possible start indexes, then through all possible end indexes for each start index, this gets you the substring. Then you loop through all other strings and check if they contain this substring. Then take the longest substring and remove it from every string (as in `strings[i]=strings[i].replace(substring,"")` ). Repeat the process all over again until no common substring is found.

EDIT: okay, I have coded it.

```
def remove_longest_substring(strings_to_check):
    # maximum common substring found so far
    # initialized with one character just so we don't loop through 1-char substrings
    max_substring = "1";

    # find all substring candidates
    for starting_index in range(0,len(strings_to_check[0])-1):
        # we need only the substrings longer than current max_substring
        for ending_index in range(starting_index+len(max_substring)+1,len(strings_to_check[0])+1):
            candidate_substring = strings_to_check[0][starting_index:ending_index]
            found_in_all = True
            for i in range(1,len(strings_to_check)):
                if strings_to_check[i].find(candidate_substring) == -1:
                    found_in_all = False
                    break
            if found_in_all:
                # found a new common substring longer than the previous one
                max_substring = candidate_substring
    if max_substring == "1":
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(len(strings_to_check)):
            strings_to_check[i] = strings_to_check[i].replace(max_substring,"")
        return True;

def remove_all_substrings(strings_to_check):
    while remove_longest_substring(strings_to_check):
        pass

lines_to_check1=["FooOne", "FooTwo", "FooThree"]
remove_all_substrings(lines_to_check1)
print lines_to_check1
lines_to_check2=["BarOneBar", "BarTwoBar", "BarThreeBar"]
remove_all_substrings(lines_to_check2)
print lines_to_check2
lines_to_check2_2=["FooOneBar", "FooTwoBar", "FooThreeBar"]
remove_all_substrings(lines_to_check2_2)
print lines_to_check2_2
lines_to_check3=["OneFooTwoBar", "TwoFooThreeBar", "ThreeFooFourBar"]
remove_all_substrings(lines_to_check3)
print lines_to_check3
```

Comment: I got the idea. If there will be no implementations on C#, I'll accept answer and implement code on C# myself. Thanks anyway, I got the clue)

Comment: Did you get the idea about catching all substrings?

Comment: Yep! Honestly right now I need exactly case 1 that you've implemented. Just tried to lake a look little deeper, to get some more universal approach.

Comment: I'm nearly done coding that anyway, will post in a few min

Comment: Coded, posted. The new solution depends on passing arrays as parameters by reference. But if you have to pass them by value, you just need a way to return both the modified array and a flag from `remove_longest_substring`.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer - it's just too big to put in a comment.

You've done an important first step by defining some test cases - given certain inputs, you expect certain outputs.

It's not a bad idea to create some unit tests around those test cases, something like this:

Create a unit test project with your incomplete class - you haven't determined yet how it's going to do what you want it to do. You can tell I didn't put much work into naming them. Names are easy to change so getting hung up on it just delays solving the problem.

One detail is that I'm only focusing on the primary part of the problem, *finding* the substrings. Replacing is another step, and it's much easier.

```
public class UnknownSubstringFinder
{
    public IEnumerable<string>FindCommonSubstrings(IEnumerable string input)
    {

    }
}
```

Then write a few tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnknownSubstringFinderTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void FindsSubstringsCommonToEachInputString()
    {
        var subject = new UnknownSubstringFinder();
        var input = new string[]{"FooOne","FooTwo","FooThree"}
        var output = subject.FindCommonSubstrings(input).ToList();
        assert.IsTrue(output.Contains("Foo"));
    }
}
```

You might stop and write the class to solve that problem before considering other cases. But perhaps you've already realized that there are other questions.

- Do you want to remove *all* substrings, or only those of a certain minimum length? (Do you want to remove any letter that appears in multiple strings?)
- Do you want the search to be case-sensitive or case-insensitive?

Based on that it might make sense to modify the class somewhat.

```
public class UnknownSubstringFinder
{
    public IEnumerable<string>FindCommonSubstrings(IEnumerable string input, int minimumLength = 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Then you can write some tests to ensure that all of the common strings are found.

```
[TestMethod]
public void FindsSubstringsCommonToEachInputString()
{
    var subject = new UnknownSubstringFinder();
    var input = new string[]{"HelloFromWorld","WorldFromHello","FromWorldHello"}
    var output = subject.FindCommonSubstrings(input, 5).ToList();
    assert.IsTrue(output.Contains("Hello"));
    assert.IsTrue(output.Contains("World"));
    assert.AreEqual(2, output.Count); // ensure no other matches
}
```

What's interesting about this approach is that it helps us discover exactly what we're trying to accomplish and what the edge cases might be. If there are requirements we haven't thought of, this helps us to see them. I hadn't really thought it through when I first read the question.

For example, this revealed the need to separate *finding* the strings and *replacing* them. Perhaps you supply an input and find that there are two matching substrings, and you have to decide which one to remove. If you remove one, the other substring might no longer be present in all of the replaced strings.

As I said, this isn't really an answer to your question. It's just a way to help solve it. Another reason why unit tests are especially helpful is because as you solve each scenario it gives you an easy way to verify that you've solved them all and that the last one you solved doesn't undo the first one. Before learning unit tests I would have done this by outputting to the console and manually looking at the output to see if I got the right result. But that means I have to go through each test case over and over. This way you can just run all of your tests to see which cases are working. It's much faster and more reliable.

And it provides a simple way to document what you expect the behavior to be instead of just remembering it. The tests tell you what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Take a look only at case one. There must be a desicion in this case.

Comment: Based on your comments and the edited question, it looks like you might want to start with a minimum number of characters (or not - you could start with one) and get all of the matching substrings that have that many characters or more. Then remove the longest matching substring that you find. It's possible that you'll find multiple substrings with the same length and you'll need to pick which one to remove. It's an interesting, solvable problem. I might poke at it later today when I have more time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why nobody's offered this as the solution:

```
        var l1 = new List<string>() {"FooOne", "FooTwo", "FooThree" };
        var r1 = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s in l1)
        {
            r1.Add(s.Replace(UnknownString1, "").Replace(UnknownString2, ""));
        }
        // Result should be:
        var r1 = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
        
        // Case 1:
        var l1 = new List<string>() {"FooOne", "FooTwo", "FooThree" };
        // Case 2:
        //var l2 = new List<string>() { "BarOneBar", "BarTwoBar", "BarThreeBar" };
        // Case 3:
        //var l3 = new List<string>() { "OneFooTwoBar", "TwoFooThreeBar", "ThreeFooFourBar" };
```

Which works for all three cases.  Regardless of what values are placed into the `l1` list, the output is always `r1 = { "One", "Two", "Three" }`
The `UnknownString1` and `UnknownString2` variables can change to anything.
In fact, if you turn it into a method you could do something like this:

```
        public static string RemoveString(this string str, string removalTarget)
        {
            return str.Replace(removalTarget, "");
        }
        
        public static string RemoveStrings(this string str, string[] removalTargets)
        {
            foreach (string s in removalTargets)
            {
                str = str.RemoveString(s);
            }
            return str;
        }

        public static string RemoveStringsFromList(this List<string> strs, string[] removalTargets)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            foreach (string s in strs)
            {
                result.Add(s.RemoveStrings, removalTargets);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Then you simply implement it in your code like this:

```
        var l3 = new List<string>() { "OneFooTwoBar", "TwoFooThreeBar", "ThreeFooFourBar" };
        var removeThis = new List<string>() { "Foo", "Bar" };

        var r3 = l3.RemoveStringsFromList(removeThis);
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you don't have a specification for the desired behaviour. You *could* say "remove any substring that exists in all supplied strings", but you could end up with some unexpected behaviour, e.g.

```
Input: "FooTwo", "FooThree", "FooTwelve"
Output: "wo", "hree", "welve"
```

You could instead say "remove any Pascal Case substring that exists in all supplied strings". That would work for the supplied examples, although the supplied examples don't look to me like representative examples of your real data.

Once you have well-defined desired behaviour, you will likely find that writing the implementation is fairly straightforward.